# RegEx and MySQL basics - replacing a varying part of a string

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a field in my table that holds a string denoting some object levels, like so:

```
"<3<"
"<3<5<"
"<3<5<49<"
```

etc.

I have a function that is to remove a level from such a string, without knowing the position of the level in the string itself. Concretely, I would like to remove "3". The result should be:

```
"0"
"<5<"
"<5<49<"
```

If I would, however, want to remove 5, and not 3, the result should be this:

```
"<3<"
"<3<"
"<3<49<"
```

Lastly, if I chose to remove 49 instead of 3 or 5, I would like to get this:

```
"<3<"
"<3<5<"
"<3<5<"
```

As you can see, the position of the substring that is to be removed varies - sometimes it's the leftmost one, sometimes in the middle, sometimes the rightmost one. What is important after all this is:

1. If the number I am removing is the only value, enclosed in "less than" signs (as in "<3<" while removing 3), the new result must be 0.
2. If the number I am removing is not the only value, the only thing that matters is that the final notation stays the same - as in, the entire string must remain enclosed in "less than" symbols, and substrings of multiple "less than" symbols in a row must not happen (as in, "3<<5<" is not allowed).

Is there an easy regex way to handle this with php and mysql, or should I just make 3 manual checks?

P.S. While I may have posed it as such, this is not homework but an actual work issue.

Comment: I don't know what objects you're storing in your database but the structure is a pure horror.

Comment: This is a categories tree. I have no say in changing the structure itself, unfortunately. The x<y notation indicates a parent-child relationship between category IDs. I myself would have gone with an additional table defining these relationships, but planning would hear none of it because they wanted the entire branch of a subject immediately recognizable without using count(explode("<", $string)) joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each line two replacements: (for example, you want to remove "3")

```
replace "^<3<$" -> "0"; 
replace "<3" -> "";
```

Comment: Thanks. While the other answers are technically correct, I wanted a regex answer and I got it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 steps.
Suppose your input is this

```
"<3<"
"<3<5<"
"<3<5<49<"
```

and you want to remove number 3:

Step 1. Since the values always start with "<", you can try to replace "<3" with "". Then the input becomes

```
"<"
"<5<"
"<5<49<"
```

Step 2. Replace strings which EQUALS "<" with 0. Then you can get

```
"0"
"<5<"
"<5<49<"
```

It's the same if you want to remove 5 or 49.
I think you can easily use regex to do these steps.

Answer (score 1):

In the first step:

```
replace "<3(?=<)"
```

I'ts important to use lookaheads, otherwise you could be replacing something like **<3**4 and that's not what you want.

Second step:

```
replace "^<$" with "0"
```